# sql the job was stopped prior to completion by shutdown sequence 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent, transactional-replication

I've transaction replication set up and running fine but today my Log Reader agent started having this warning :

> sql the job was stopped prior to completion by shutdown sequence 0 . The job was invoked by start sequence 0.

I've looked through all the SQL/agent/Windows logs and I can't see anything special. Has anyone ever faced the same issue?

PS: This server has log shipping running for 30dbs and also has other 3 transactional publications if it helps. This is the only job that is giving me this error. We are running on SQL Server 2008.

Thank you